# 5v adaptor to 6v 6.4w UPDATED

Tags: step-up

I have a lot of 5v 400mah to 2a adaptors laying around. 
Is it possible to use this on an old camera with input 6v 6.4w? 
The battery is out of the camera and the power would only go thru the camera and not the battery.
If this makes a difference.

I read something on step-up converters but don't really know how that works or if it's safe.
And how would I be able to get the correct circuit to get 6v 6.4 watts of power.

Not really sure where to start?

So I tried a 5v 3A adaptor and it still didn't go on.

I tried finding more info and I found a picture of the charger online.

pictures below!

The charger says 6v - 11.8w 
So I would need more than 5v 3a charger correct.

Or could it be that the camera needs a battery to work? (it's a phillips VKR 6847/00)
[image: bottom of the camera]
[image: back of the charger of the camera]

Comment: Look up or google boost regulator.

Comment: If the camera is designed to work on batteries, it probably isn't that fussy about the voltage.  Have you tried running it on 5V using an adaptor of not less than 1.5A?

Comment: Does it work on batteries? If so, try to measure the real battery voltage during operation. But in general questions on the use of electronic devices are considered off-topic here. because they are very device specific bringing little use for later readers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to provide 6.4W at 6V, you need to have about 1A at 6V or 1.25A at 5V. You may get away with 1A 5V adapter because devices usually specify slightly more than their maximum power requirement.
Second of all, as long as you get a step-up converter capable of providing at least 2A (I would recommend a 3A converter so that it doesn't run hot at 1A), you should be fine, but it has to be able to run at 5V or even 4.5V at its input.
 You could use any adjustable step-up (or boost) module with an LM2577 or XL6009 (slightly better than LM2577, according to specs).
Here is one as an example:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32762092828.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.21975c735s1w7H&algo_pvid=5fa4a4d4-f49c-473d-82df-5dd3d10e15c7&algo_expid=5fa4a4d4-f49c-473d-82df-5dd3d10e15c7-1&btsid=0ab50a5715870295770894662e90dc&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_